# Что означает "опыт коммерческой разработки" на С++

Tags: c++

Какие нужны знания что бы утверждать, что есть опыт коммерческой разработки на С++. Просьба, не писать необдуманных ответов.

Comment: ох, за формулировку "тупые ответы" можно минус получить.

Comment: >Просьба, не писать необдуманных ответов

справедливости ради, любой отвечающий будет считать свой ответ самым что ни есть взвешенным и обдуманным

Comment: @voipp, просьба не писать необдуманных вопросов..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В общем-то элементарно - опыт коммерческой разработки С++ подразумевает работу С++-программистом, причем вне зависимости от типа - будь то работа в офисе, удаленная работа, фриланс или какие-то другие формы сотрудничества, в том числе и без трудового договора или договора найма (то есть важен именно опыт таковой работы. Хотя, весьма возможно, что опыт фрилансерской деятельности может по разным причинам цениться ниже. Однако же его тоже можно отнести к пресловутому "опыту коммерческой разработки"). Разумеется, написание лабораторных работ по 500 рублей за штуку сюда не входит, и это еще один критерий - имеет значение скорее всего сам факт разработки сколько-нибудь существенного ПО, а следовательно и понимания принципов разработки и способность кандидата подтвердить свои навыки. Возможно, что собеседующего (ведь речь о вакансиях, не так ли?) устроит и факт деятельного участия в каком-нибудь более-менее существенном опенсорсном проекте (хотя не уверен - для некоторых собеседующих, а уж тем более рекрутеров даже факт наличия богатого прошлого на Гитхабе или регулярные коммиты в ядро Linux мало о чем скажет (несколько утрирую, но, думаю, мысль понятна)). В общем, в основном "опыт коммерческой разработки"  - это (помимо опыта работы и записи в трудовой книжке)  то, что отличает студента без опыта от хотя бы джуниора, и позволяет понять, что соискатель занимался чем-то более серьезным, нежели курсовые проекты, формошлёпство и велосипедостроение

Answer (score 9):

это значит только одно - приложение, которое разрабатывалось, прямо или косвенно приносило деньги. То есть:

- приложение продавалось Вами непосредственно.
- приложение продавалось фирмой, которая платила Вам зарплату.
- приложение было "бесплатным" сервером, а для доступа к нему, людям нужно было покупать отдельное (не зависящее от Вас) приложение, например, клиент на адроиде.

Отсюда вывод. Вам не знания нужны, а просто список приложений. То есть, ответ должен быть такой: "работал N лет в фирме ABC, которая делала продукт ZZZ (можно посмотреть на сайте www.previouscompany.com). Я в этом продукте делал функциональность YYY".